# I want to open a page within a webView with facebook connect already authenticated

Tags: iphone, facebook, authentication

I have built an iphone game that allows a user to generate scores.  It also allows the user to post his scores to a central DB.  User identification and authentication relies on Facebook connect.  In fact, I downloaded the Facebook Connect demo app from github a few months ago and hacked my game into it.

I also built a web app on top of GAE to do leaderboard functionality so my future armies of users can see how they compare to other players.  I have taken advantage of the facebook tools to allow them to compete against just their friends.

Life is good.

I would like to be able to display the leaderboard to the user within the iphone app, instead of forcing them to open safari to go to my webapp.  A crude way of doing this would be to create another view accessible via a tabbedViewController and fill the second tab with a webView directed to my (appropriately formatted) webapp.

This brings me to my problem.  When the user arrives at the web page for the first time, they have to authenticate.  This is fine when you are surfing the web.  However, in a bare bones webview embedded in an iphone app, it looks stupid.  I just authenticated on the other tab (so I could post my score).  Why do I have to authenticate again?

So, I would like to use the Facebook Connect tools to open my web app in an already-authenticated status.  However, it seems like that would mean reusing an authentication token, which I assume is prohibited.  I have two questions:

Is this possible?

If so, how might I do it?

Thanks for any help.  I realize this is involved so I'm happy to clarify if it's unclear.

Dessie

Answer (score 0):

You can re-use that access token. For an example, when you make a graph call with the FB iOS SDK you are using that token to authenticate the call.

To do what you are trying to do - at least how I would do it, is by using the fb javascript sdk. Reference : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Make sure each page of your web app has the script include and ensure FB.Init() is being called with the proper parameters (AppID, etc). Since you are using the FB iOS SDK your cookies should be set and everything should work as planned and the user should already be authenticated. If not - try this code:

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.session) {
    // logged in and connected user, someone you know
  } else {
    // no user session available, someone you dont know
  }
});

If that all works, then you can make calls to the REST API or Graph like so:

FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  alert(response.name);
});

-Joey

Answer (score 0):

You could also use move the webview back and forth between the tabs (when/if the user changes tabs).